# c++ /ubuntu about .a and .so

Tags: c++, ubuntu

HI,

I would like to ask what is better to use: the .a or the .so file? If i have for example an .so(or .a) and the header.h file can i use these 2 in a test.cpp code without needing the header.cpp? Can i go on a computer just with these 2 and create my own test program?

Secondly I would like to ask if .a is better to use what is the command in ubuntu for creating the .a file? And one more question. Do I necessarly need to use extern "C" class* object() {return new class} in the header.cpp. Or can i use extern"C" in the test.cpp code after i include the .a or .so and the .h file? THX!

The compile command is: `g++ test.cpp -o test -ldl` (//i dont want to include header.cpp here in the command line when i compile the test.cpp code

Comment: There are several questions here and should be split up - then I suspect found as duplicates - please search SO first

Answer (score 1):

.a and .so serve different purposes. One is for statically linking the other one is for shared linking to your library. Search for these terms and you should get a fair amount of answers.